# Apple Mach O Linker error?

Tags: c++, linker-errors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

using namespace std;




int main()
{

    string text;
    string numbers;
    string characters;
    string spaces;

    getline(cin, text);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            characters += text[i];
        }
        else if (isdigit(text[i]))
        {
            numbers +=text[i];
        }
        else
        {
            spaces +=text[i];
        }
    }

    cout<<"Numbers in the string: "<<numbers<<endl
    <<"Alphabets in the string: "<<characters<<endl
    <<"Spaces in the string: "<<spaces.length()<<endl<<endl;


    string searchstr;
    string replacestr;
    double n = text.length();

    cout<<"Enter a word to search: "<<endl;

    getline(cin, searchstr);

    cout<<"Enter a replacement word: "<<endl;

    getline (cin, replacestr);

    double position = text.find(searchstr, 0);

    text.replace (position, n, replacestr);

    cout<<"Replaced string is: "<<endl
    <<text<<endl<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Can't figure out what's going on here. Does it have to do with the librarys being used?

```
Error:
Ld "/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project_4-fgfiiphpwijunsfidkthbsqbxgvb/Build/Products/Debug/Project 4" normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/andy/Desktop/EECS138/Project 4"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.8
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project_4-fgfiiphpwijunsfidkthbsqbxgvb/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project_4-fgfiiphpwijunsfidkthbsqbxgvb/Build/Products/Debug -filelist "/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project_4-fgfiiphpwijunsfidkthbsqbxgvb/Build/Intermediates/Project 4.build/Debug/Project 4.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Project 4.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -stdlib=libc++ -o "/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project_4-fgfiiphpwijunsfidkthbsqbxgvb/Build/Products/Debug/Project 4"

duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project_4-fgfiiphpwijunsfidkthbsqbxgvb/Build/Intermediates/Project 4.build/Debug/Project 4.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project_4-fgfiiphpwijunsfidkthbsqbxgvb/Build/Intermediates/Project 4.build/Debug/Project 4.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/File.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation
```

Not sure why Xcode fails to build/run the program, it worked perfectly fine in CodeBlocks. Any help as to why It gives me this error?

Comment: can you post the full error

Comment: 'Tis not an Xcode question.

Comment: If you're using a main.m file, rename it to main.mm and try it then.

Answer (score 0):

From your error, it appears that you have a file `main` and another file `File` that **both define the `main()` function.**

`main()` is the entry point for your program.  You cannot define two different functions for your program to begin.

Comment: Silly me. That was it. Thanks